# Can we set question formatting?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Here is some suggestion to change question formatting.

I have edited some question regarding it. 
whenever question is asked and it's about to magento 2.
some people write question like below format.

"**Magento2 question**"

"**Magento2-question**"
"**Magento 2 - question**"

"**Magento2 : question**"
"**Magento 2 : question**"

"**Magento2 | question**"
"**Magento 2 | question**"

They always add new symbols so in my personal opinion why we are giving them to add deliminator for question. we can set plain text in question 
or we can give them suggestion text like "**Magento 2 question**" so it would be go in proper way for next all questions.

Comment: How about we put the version in the tags and not in the title?

Comment: that is great but still people are writing in title

Comment: those does not make sense to change version format, it does not make any useful impact

Comment: Is there any specific usecase for having it more standardized in the title?

Comment: It is more readable & quick searchable from google .. Thanks to SE great search mechanism it is also searching like this question also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I don't see any added value to have the magento version in the title, or not to have it either.
There is no point to set a standard or to start editing all the questions to reflect the magento version in the title or to not reflect it.

Comment: Yes, there is no possibilities to set standard as not much useful. Agree.  thanks for the time.